# Python com excel (Openpyxl) - pegar o resultado da fórmula ao invés da fórmula em si

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Fala galera, tudo bom? primeira vez por aqui. Tenho uma planilha no excel com diversas formulas, e queria que meu código do python pegasse pra mim apenas o resultado dessas formulas, e não a formula em si, exemplo:

```
import openpyxl
ficha=str(input("Informe o nome da ficha: "))
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(ficha+'.xlsx')
NH=wb["PERÍCIAS"]['D4'].value
print(NH)
```

E no resultado do print, nós temos:

> =IF(E4 ="DX",ATRIBUTOS!B5+F4,IF(E4="IQ",ATRIBUTOS!B7+F4,IF(E4="ST",ATRIBUTOS!B3+F4,IF(E4="HT",ATRIBUTOS!B9+F4,""))))

Ele me dá o que eu escrevi na célula do excel, a fórmula, ao invés de um simples "12" que é o resultado dessa conta kkkk. Será que é possível fazer o que eu quero? Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1):

A função `load_workbook()` pode receber o parâmetro nomeado `data_only`, que define se as células que contém fórmula devem guardar a própria fórmula (padrão), ou devem guardar resultado da última execução da fórmula (na última vez que o excel leu a planilha e a executou).

Então:

- `data_only = True` -> A property `value` retornará o último valor resultante da última execução da fórmula.
- `data_only = False` -> A property `value` retornará a fórmula armazenada na célula. (padrão)